# ALl request to Yii2 API on Digital Ocean is giving 404 Not Found respond

Tags: yii2, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean, yii2-advanced-app

I am deploying my first yii2 api on Digital ocean with ubuntu 16.04. I receive a 404 not found response for all request i make to the API. This same API works fine locally without any issues.

I have setup LAMPP and link up my DB to my API,
I have installed an SSL Certificate to the domain and it works great. 
When i host the API as follows; 
/var/www/html/myfolder/api/....

no request works on this API eg

https://example.com/myfolder/api/web/v1/beforeauths/trending

I have a .htaccess inside .../api/web with the following rules

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

I also have an .htaccess inside ../api folder with the following containg

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

I do not know what I have miss out surely in my configurations. Any help on this will be great

Comment: Are you sure that you have enabled rewrite module in your Apache config?

Comment: pls how do I do that ??? because i cant remember doing such

Answer (score 0):

I did sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

then I added the this rule

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
. . .
 # 
 # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
 # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
 # Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
 #
 AllowOverride All
. . .
</Directory>
```

Restarted apache as

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```